# How to get Truffle to generate artifacts for contracts outside of project?

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

Say I have a contract `MyToken.sol` which has already been deployed to a public Ethereum network. Its source is maintained in an external repository and is included in my `package.json` file so that it falls under the `node_modules/` directory. I create my own contract `MyContract.sol` in the local project's `contracts/` directory. In order to prevent compiling the entire contract (and its imported contracts) of `MyToken.sol`, I use an interface `IMyToken.sol` in my local project to give `MyContract.sol` only the functions that it needs from `MyToken.sol`. This is also beneficial to prevent Truffle from displaying compiler warnings for older contracts which have already been deployed.

The project structure is as follows:

```
MyProject
    |
    |
    +- contracts
    |     |
    |     +- interfaces
    |     |     |
    |     |     +- IMyToken.sol
    |     |
    |     +- MyContract.sol
    |
    +- node_modules
          |
          +- my_token
                |
                +- contracts
                      |
                      +- MyToken.sol
```

The source of `MyContract.sol` is similar to the following:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "interfaces/IMyToken.sol";

contract MyContract {
  IMyToken token = IMyToken(0x...);
  ...
}
```

Compiling this locally works perfectly fine. I can even deploy it to a network where `MyToken` is already deployed and interact with it as expected. However, for local testing, I need to deploy my own instance of `MyToken.sol`, but I want to avoid including it in my project. Since the actual `MyToken.sol` is not located within my project's `contracts/` directory, Truffle does not generate artifacts for it. Therefore, the following does *not* work for any migrations script:

```
var MyToken = artifacts.require("../node_modules/my_token/contracts/MyToken.sol");
```

My question is: **What is the best practice for generating artifacts in Truffle for contracts which reside outside of the local project?**

To give one possible solution (which I'm not too fond of), I can create a `contracts/lib/` directory and store a base contract which imports from the `node_modules/` directory. For example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "my_token/contracts/MyToken.sol";
```

The only problem that I have with this solution is I still get all of the old compiler warnings because `MyToken` was deployed with an older Solidity version.

Comment: Perhaps you want to publish your contract with truffle https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/package-management-via-ethpm and import it from there, or use semantic versioning. Try asking https://slack.openzeppelin.org/ as they work with these kind of things a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In order to deploy a different project, you need its `json` compiler output, within this file you'd find the compiled `bytecode` which can then be deployed locally for testing.

Doing so using `ethers.js` is pretty easy. For instance to deploy the WETH native token wrapper you first install `npm i -D canonical-weth`, it'll then reside in your `node_modules` dir, now use it the following way in your `test.js` -

```
const compiledWETH = require("canonical-weth/build/contracts/WETH9.json");
const factoryWETH = new ethers.ContractFactory(compiledWETH.abi, compiledWETH.bytecode, ownerAccount);
const WETH = await factoryWETH.deploy();
```

after that you'll have WETH deployed at `WETH.address`, ready for your tests.